# Defaults for robots meta tag

Tags: html, seo, meta-tags, robots.txt

If I don't specify a robots meta tag in the head of the document, the defaults are:

```
<meta name="robots" content="index,follow">
```

My question is, if I only specify "noindex", is the default still "follow"? So if I specify this below, is the default still follow?

```
<meta name="robots" content="noindex">
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about SEO

Comment: Yes, the default behavior is to follow the links on that page

Comment: @JohnConde — It appears to be within the scope of SEO topics are suitable for Stackoverflow as described by the SEO tag wiki. It is a question about how clients are supposed to behave given a piece of HTML. It isn't looking for anything opinionated or entirely based around guessing secret algorithms.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by only specifying the noindex, it will still be follow.
More information can be found [here]{https://developers.google.com/webmasters/control-crawl-index/docs/robots_meta_tag}

Answer (score 1):

While "noindex" would be the same as "noindex,follow", it is important to note, that a long-term noindex will lead to "noindex,nofollow"; regardless of the specified follow-value. Although this is only valid for Google, i guess this is not what you intend.

some source:
https://blog.seoprofiler.com/google-noindexfollow-noindexnofollow-long-run/
(or just google for "long term noindex"